# FedEx WSDL help on ASP.NET (VB) Web App

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, wsdl, fedex

My web app currently uses the old FedEx WSDL API for rates and tracking and I have to now test it for FedEx's SHA-2 changes coming in Jan 2016.

I am a little confused about how to easily switch between "Production Environment" and "Test Environment" and need some advice.

I will first explain how the Web Service is currently integrated into my app so you understand the context of my question:

I initially uploaded the FedEx WSDL files to my second server (not the actual server the website app is on) and "Added Web Reference" to the remote url in my project.  This may not have been necessary and there may have been an easier way (locally for instance) but because I did not fully understand how it all works this was the easiest route for me at the time.

This created an "App_WebReferences" folder within my project and within that a WSDL file and a discomap file for the track and rate services.

I also have two key/value pairs in my Web.config file under  that point to these web references and gateway.fedex.com.  I can't remember if I manually created them or if the WSDL import did it automatically.

I know that for testing purposes I need to use the "gatewaybeta.fedex.com" url and my FedEx "Test Credentials" not my "Production Credentials" but I am confused how it all works and where exactly I need to swap over the endpoint urls.

For instance, can I just change the url in the Web.config file or do I have to also change it in the WebReference and the original imported WSDL files that are on my second remote server?

After the import, is the WSDL file on the second remote server even needed or used in a live call by my app to the FedEx web service or can it be deleted now?

The discomap file references the original wsdl file location on my second server so how does that work and what would happen if I deleted the wsdl file from my second server?

Ultimately what I would like to do is create a simple admin FedEx web page with a basic form on it where I can enter a default FedEx tracking number and/or shipment details and then select from a drop-down list between TEST and PRODUCTION and have the aspx.vb code handle the url/credential changes so I don't have to manually change wsdls and webreferences and web.config file keys etc.

Hope someone can clarify this for me and set me on the right track!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Switching from test to production**

1. If you haven't created your production credentials yet, go to the [FedEx Web Services](http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/index.html) page, click "Move to Production" and follow the instructions. Your organization will need a FedEx customer account and you will need that info.
2. In your Visual Studio project, change the URLs in Properties\Settings.settings and App.config/Web.config. (If you use the UI to change Settings.settings, the config file will update automatically.)
3. Update the project to use your production credentials.

Consider taking advantage of [config transformations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx) to keep your test and production credentials in different config files.

**How to add the web reference**

What you did (placing FedEx's WSDLs on your own server so you can add the web reference using an http link) is fine but was a little more work than was necessary.

Next time you need to do this, simply keep the WSDLs on your own computer, and when you add the web reference, *use a local file path* (ex: C:\Users\Desktop\RateService.wsdl).

**The WSDL and discomap files**

These files are only used by Visual Studio to create the proxy classes. They are not referenced during the actual service calls. You could delete them but, for future reference, make sure they are part of your project.

I don't think there's a problem with the discomap pointing to the WSDL on a different server even if that address no longer exists. I think this reference is only used if you were to update the web reference (right click > Update Web Reference), which you shouldn't be doing because you're supposed to download the latest WSDLs from FedEx's developer site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and for the helpful information.  From what you stated it sounds as if once you have added the web reference the original WSDL file on the remote sever is redundant and that all the information needed to use the service is now in the project...correct?

Comment: And with regard to placing the WSDL file locally on your development computer, I assume that the same applies...it only needs to be there for the "add web reference" process and once this has been done it can be deleted and doesn't need to be uploaded to the live server since all of the information is already within the project...correct?

Comment: Finally, to be absolutely clear, the web.config endpoint url for the service overrides the endpoint url in the discomap and imported WSDL files?

Comment: You're a star!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

FYI: I have found the easiest way to switch between production and test environment endpoint urls and credentials is simply to change the service class object values within the code behind of the page according to the admin user's drop-down list selection.

So if they choose "Test" it's TrackService.Url = "gatewaybeta.fedex.com" and if it's "Production" then it's TrackService.Url = "gateway.fedex.com".

This overrides the endpoints in the web.config and WSDL files.

You have to remember to swap the key/password/meternumber credentials too.